# PHP: YES/NO Qustion

Tags: javascript, php

I write the code for deletion , the code ask the user are you sure to delete ?

But the code is not working .

Can anyone write code is worked ?

Comment: The understand of the question falid successfully!

Comment: Try to use ajax for this kind of functionality

Comment: PHP is executed on the **server**, and Javascript is executed in the **browser**, these are two *different* environments. you can't mix PHP & JS code like this.

Comment: Not to be mean but this code is totally wrong, you are open to sql injection here, you have spelling mistakes in your alert and like the comment above states you should use Ajax. you really need to understand the language you are using better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm message should be add to delete link, not in delete script.

Something link:

```
<a href="item_delete.php?id=<?php echo $item->id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete information?')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the answers yes in the confirm box a specific action has to be performed, otherwise the system doesn't have to do anything. This application has two sides, first javascript where the user can act on the website, and the second step is that javascript is calling a PHP script that really is deleting the thing.

First javascript

```
var r=confirm("Do you really want to delete this universe?");
if (r==true)
{
    // possible to perform jQuery get request
    // https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
}
```

Second PHP

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

mysql_query("DELETE FROM omniverse WHERE universeID = {$id}") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have to make sure that the ID is passed through the javascript to the PHP code. I allready see some answers where the javascript is performed inside the A HREF link.